# How can I scroll to a component by component key prop?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that renders the following child components:

```
            Object.values(eventData).map((event) => {
                return (
                    <EventsSection
                        key={event.id}
                        eventID={event.id}
                        eventDate={event.date}
                    />
                );
            })
```

Assuming there are 10-20 records in `eventData` - upon a certain user action, how can i make the browser window to scroll onto an `EventSection` records based on its `key` prop?

Comment: provide `event.id` as `id` of any native html element that resides inside `EventsSection` and then its as easy as doing an [anchor scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=anchor+scroll)

Comment: To complete @boop_the_snoot comment. If `EventsSection` is provided by a third party library, you can still wrap the `EventsSection` inside a `div` element for example, and pass the id to that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `ref` from the id. Something like the below would be enough if the user wanted to click on the list and make the browser scroll to that `ref`.

```js
function renderEventSection(props) {
  const { key, name } = props
  const ref = useRef()

  const handleClick = () =>
    ref.current.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start',
    });

  return (
    <div key={key} ref={ref} onClick={handleClick}>
      {name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you need to scroll from outside the list, just move that logic to the parent component or use a React Context (See second example). Also, if you need another event, just change it to any other desired user interaction.

- [Example for the code above](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-wood-8tyoq) (Click on any of the Data list item)
- [Example with the scroll from the parent component](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-mirzakhani-lvbb7) (Click on any of the buttons and window will scroll to the desired number)

Comment: Btw, i guess i can't assign a `ref` using `useRef()` to a class component?..